# How to properly use PayloadAction with meta type in redux-toolkit? meta not giving all properties i want

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In Redux tool it I am passing user argument (email , password,) to login.
In action it is comming (Meta payload) it's comming only email and password. But in backend i am passing (name, email, password, and token). how can i get whole payload?

[image]

[image]

`

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('user/loginuser', async(user, 
  thunkAPI) =>{
   try {
    const response = customFetch.post('/auth/login', **user**)
    console.log(response, "response");
    return response.data
   } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.msg)
   }
})
```

`

`

```
**ExtraReducers** 
.addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) =>{
    state.isLoading = true;
  })

  .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, {**meta**}, action) =>{
    console.log(action, "action");
    const {arg: user} = meta;
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.user = user;
    addUserToLocalStorage(user)
    toast.success(`Hello There ${user.email}`);
  })

  .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, {payload}) =>{
    state.isLoading = false;
    toast.error(payload)
  })
```

`

I am trying to get whole object I am passing as argument. it's giving in Meta only email and password.

Answer (score 0):

You are using meta.arg to get the response which is wrong. `meta.arg` contains the data that you pass when you call that reducer function. In your example, you pass `email` and `password`.

If you want to get the response, there's another key `payload`. It will have the response.

```
.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, { meta, payload }) =>{
    console.log(payload)
})
```

Also add await before `customFetch.post('/auth/login', **user**)` to wait for the promise to resolve

Comment: If provided, all arguments from the action creator will be passed to the prepare callback, and it should return an object with the payload field (otherwise the payload of created actions will be undefined). Additionally, the object can have a meta and/or an error field that will also be added to created actions. meta may contain extra information about the action, error may contain details about the action failure. 
userSlice.js:74 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'payload' of '_ref4' as it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you It's working now, Actually i forgot to add await.... in async function...